# How to generate angular components using jdl file in jhipster geenrate front end application

Tags: jhipster

I have separated the front end and back end code using jhipster and question is how to use same jdl file which we used to generate the back end code to generate the front end angular components.

Comment: Have you tried to just import it  with `jhipster import-jdl` in both locations ?

Comment: it works with jhipster import-jdl --skip-server